# Group object has no attribute user_set

Tags: python, django, django-admin, usergroups

I'm using a custom User created with AbstractBaseUser and I tried to add users to a specific group using the django admin. But there were no option to add users to a group. So I found a solution from the stack overflow and It gave me the capability to add users to the group I created. But after saving the user It gives me an error saying **Group object has no attribute user_set**

My User Model

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an username")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=80, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Code I got from the stackoverflow

```
User = get_user_model()


# Create ModelForm based on the Group model.
class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = []

    # Add the users field.
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
         queryset=User.objects.all(),
         required=False,
         # Use the pretty 'filter_horizontal widget'.
         widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('users', False)
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do the normal form initialisation.
        super(GroupAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # If it is an existing group (saved objects have a pk).
        if self.instance.pk:
            # Populate the users field with the current Group users.
            self.fields['users'].initial = self.instance.user_set.all()

    def save_m2m(self):
        # Add the users to the Group.
        self.instance.user_set.set(self.cleaned_data['users'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Default save
        instance = super(GroupAdminForm, self).save()
        # Save many-to-many data
        self.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

Why this is giving me the error and is there any solutions for this

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django implements group relation in [`PermissionsMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin) so you don't have that particular relation

You can implement `AbstractUser` class instead or add the Mixin

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
```

Comment: Now I can add users to groups. But when I log into the admin panel with a user in a specific group I can not see permissions that I granted to that user. Ex:- I have a group called admin level 2 and I granted view users permission to that and I add admin2 user to the group.But when I log in to the admin panel using the user admin2 I can't see permissions I granted

Comment: Ok I solved that I've overidden the has_perm method